# How to freeze rotation with a Rigidbody 2D?

Tags: unity, c#, rigid-body-dynamics

So I am looking to freeze rotation in the Y axis on a Rigidbody 2D. I'm not sure how to set this in my code. This is what I have so far, can you point out my errors?

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public float speed;
    public float height;
    GameObject Player;
    RigidbodyConstraints pos;
    Transform P;
    // Update is called once per frame

    void OnAwake()
    {
        Player = GameObject.Find ("Player");
        pos = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY;
        Rigidbody2D. = pos;
    }


    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        if (Input.GetButton ("Horizontal")) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if( Input.GetButton("Left"))
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump")) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector3.up * height * Time.deltaTime);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, since you're working in 2D, you'll want to use the type `RigidbodyConstraints2D` as opposed to just `RigidbodyConstraints`.

Secondly, you can't freeze the y rotation on 2D rigidbodies, only in the z axis, which you can do by saying:

```
pos = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeRotation;
```

Equally, you could just set it in the inspector with the gameobject selected, which would save you the hassle of all this code.

Lastly, `Rigidbody2D. = pos;` in your `OnAwake()` function, which by the way should just be `Awake()`, isn't doing anything. In Unity 5 you can't call the rigidbody directly anymore, you have to find the component.

I'll leave [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) here to get you on the right track. :)

Good Luck and keep at it!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon [Anthony Ngo's answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/67552/anthony-ngo)

As of Unity 5.1 you can simply do it in the editor:

[image]

Source: http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.1 
To get to that part you can probably do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> then type `rigidbody`. Your browser should then highlight that part.